# Help with moving ALL data from one galaxy 3 to a new Galaxy 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer

I need to transfer everything from phone A to phone B (pictures, contacts, apps, and text messages).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know of a fresh and safe way to do this absolutely automatically but there are some tools which can help you with the same.

- For Call Logs and SMS you can comfortably use these two apps and then transfer the backup files they create to you new phone. - [SMS Backup and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) and [Call Logs Backup and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.CallLogBackupRestore&hl=en)
- For getting a list of your applications which you have currently installed, you may use [AppBrain App Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=en). Some time back this had a companion app to it called Fast Web Installer. I believe APKs are still available on the internet. This one will take a backup of your app list and Fast Web Installer can restore the same on the other device.
- Personally I recommend that you sign into your Google Account and go to all applications you have ever installed and manually handpick. This prevents useless or unused applications from your old phone to carry over to your new phone.
- Contacts are automatically backed up at Google and you can do the same for the pictures as well. If you want to transfer pictures, you can also transfer them via External SD Card and just use the same SD Card on your other phone.